# Find the maximum of the set $ \left\{x+y:(x,y)\in \overline{B(0,1)}\right\}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the maximum of the set $\displaystyle \left\{x+y:(x,y)\in \overline{B(0,1)}\right\}$.

As in $\overline{B(0,1)}$ maximum value of $x$ and $y$ both $1$ so maximum value will be $2$. Am I correct ?

Comment: I do not know how you thought $(1,1)$ will be an element of closed unit disk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some polar representation, you're looking for the maximum of $r(\cos(a)+\sin(a))$ with the constraints $r\in [0,1]$ and $a\in \mathbb R$.

Note that $r(\cos(a)+\sin(a))=\sqrt 2r \cos(a-\pi/4)\leq \sqrt 2$.

The equality is achieved when $r=1$ and $a=\pi/4$.

So the answer is $\sqrt 2$.